# Why do i get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: even though the build is green?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, webdriver, nosuchmethoderror

I wrote a test using HtmlUnitDriver in intellij.
The code is:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class HtmlUnitDemo {
    WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        HtmlUnitDemo obj = new HtmlUnitDemo();
        obj.setup();
        obj.openURL();
    }

    public void openURL() {

        driver.get("https://mail.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xyz");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("pqr");
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn-submit")).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "CAS – Central Authentication Service");
    }

    public void setup(){
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    }
}
```

This code builds when i use gradle. But, when I run it in the IDE, it gives me a

```
*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)
```

The entire stack trace is:

```
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:504)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:470)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.setUseInsecureSSL(HttpWebConnection.java:659)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.setUseInsecureSSL(WebClient.java:1085)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.createWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:263)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:129)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:172)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:168)
at smoke.com.thoughtworks.twu.HtmlUnitDemo.setup(HtmlUnitDemo.java:30)
at smoke.com.thoughtworks.twu.HtmlUnitDemo.main(HtmlUnitDemo.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I googled this error and it said something related to class path. But I am not sure what exactly is to be done. I am very new to this field. So any help will be deeply appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It means you are not running with the same version of code you are compiling with.

Comment: Need a stack trace, but it looks like one of the jar files in your dependencies is of the wrong version.

Comment: Yeah, there are several ways to "achieve" this, but about 95% of the time it means you compiled with one version of jar and are running with a different version, as Peter suggests.  You can also get it if you get two "paired" jars mismatched, version-wise.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchMethodError` might indicate that the library where the class `org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme` is has a different version that what is expected.

Check the dependencies used by the Selenium library you are using. If it's from maven it can be a simple task, otherwise check on their website.

Comment: I checked my dependencies. A jar is using an older version. It's still not working. I don't see how checking would fix it, downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and was very difficult for me to solve.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)
```

There are two classes on my Classpath that have the same "fully qualified" name

> org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme

Java simply picks the first Scheme class is sees and it's the wrong one. It uses the Scheme class that doesn't have the method I expect.

Ok so I fix by just declaring the right dependency in Maven right? No. Both of the Scheme classes are in different Artifacts, and one is a transitive dependency so I can't remove completely.

**Solution** We had to manually override Maven by putting the Jar of the Scheme class we want to use inside Tomcat. The dependencies picked up by the Tomcat container are loaded before the Maven dependencies. So load the Scheme class Jar into your web container so you can guarantee it's found first.

These commands were very useful while analyzing.

```
mvn dependency:analyze -o
mvn dependency:tree -o
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IntelJ IDE. Make sure you are giving right JDK in the project detail. You can check it by
Press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S -> Will open Project Settings.
click on project. You can see which JDK you are specified there.
[image: Project Setting page]
Go to your path of JDK in your system. If you are on Windows 64 bit version. it will be

C:\Program Files\Java\
Make sure The JDK you have specified also have the corresponding jre in the same  path(JDK,JRE version should be same).
[image: JDK In my system]

So you can see I have jdk1.8.0_141, jre1.8.0_141. And I have Indexed This jdk1.8.0_141 to my IntelJ.
When you are checking If you see like Corresponding JRE not present. IntelJ indexing will not be proper and it lead to such errors which you mentioned in the question.
You can download latest JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html 
If you are on windows use .exe version of JDK and run in your system. Which will automatically install corresponsind jre in the same path.
You can put your doubts on comments. Will try to help you out.

After that  come back to IntelJ. Go **project Settings->projects**. Click **New** and select and add the proper JDK. Click **OK**. Then Go to your program. you can see IntelJ Is reindexing your things. May take couple of minutes. After that try to re run the program.

Comment: JDK includes JRE. Class OP is talking about isn't in the JDK/JRE anyway. Please delete or update.